# A question on the Chinese Remainder Theorem

Tags: number-theory, commutative-algebra, algebraic-number-theory

This is a question from Lang's ANT, Thm 2 (ch.7, $\S2$).

Let $k$ be a number field and $A$ its adele group.

In the proof, Lang states

Given $x\in A$, let $m$ be a rational integer such that $mx$ has integral components for all non-Archimedean $v$. Let $S$ be the set of primes $\mathfrak p$ of $\mathcal O_k$ such that $\mathfrak p \mid m$. We can find $\alpha\in \mathcal{O}_k$ s.t. $$mx\equiv\alpha \;\;(\text{mod }\mathfrak{p}^{n})$$ for all $\mathfrak p \in S$ and for some fixed large $n$, by the *Chinese Remainder Theorem*.

This congruence is confusing me-- for a start, I assume Lang means $mx_v$ for all non-arch $v$ instead of $mx$?

Second, isn't $mx_v$ an element of $\mathcal{O}_{k_v}$, so not necessarily in $\mathcal{O}_k$ which is what we need in order to apply the CRT?

Any help will be very much appreciated.

Comment: The prime $\mathfrak{p}$ considered in the congruence is only the primes in $\mathcal{O}_k$ dividing $m$, so there are only finitely many congruences.

Comment: "Lang's ANT"? Can't you spell it out for us? Try googling it and you will see the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, Lang means $mx_{\mathfrak p}$.

Secondly, you are right that $mx_{\mathfrak p}$ is an element of $\mathcal O_{k_{\mathfrak p}}$. However, since $\mathcal O_k$ is dense in $\mathcal O_{k_{\mathfrak p}}$, we can choose an element of $\mathcal O_k$ which is congruent to it modulo $\mathfrak p^n$, and apply the C.R.T. to *these* elements. As **i707107** points out, there are finitely many primes being considered, so there is no problem after that.